# Interpret disk errors output from ras-mc-ctl --summary

Tags: linux, command, disk, output, rasdaemon

When I run `ras-mc-ctl --summary` I get the following output:

```
No Memory errors.

No PCIe AER errors.

No Extlog errors.

No devlink errors.
Disk errors summary:
    0:0 has 15356 errors
    0:2064 has 4669 errors
    0:2816 has 594 errors
No MCE errors.
```

Now, I'm not *particularly* concerned about there errors given that presumably even my CD/DVD drive which I haven't used has them given that I only have 3 SATA devices and it is one of them, but I am regardless curious, how does this number notation line up with my physical drives? If I do `lsblk` I see a similar syntax which has the header MAJ:MIN (presumably Major:Minor), but the numbers there don't line up at all with the ones here. The numbers in `lsblk` have 8 as major for all my disks and 11 as major for my CD/DVD drive, which does not line up with the numbers given to me by `ras-mc-ctl`.

How do I figure out which drives the numbers in `ras-mc-ctl --summary` correspond to and what do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsblk` will give you MAJ:MIN numbers

To calculate the equivalent for `ras-mc-ctl`, do:

```
d = (MAJ * 256) + MIN
```

To go from `ras-mc-ctl` to `lsblk`, do:

```
MAJ=int(d/256)
MIN=d % 256
```

For your case:

```
MAJ=(2064/256)=8
MIN=(2064%256)=16
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any explanation of the `0:0` disk `ras-mc-ctl` speaks of? Using that forumulate I'd end up with MAJOR = 0 and MINOR = 0 still and I have no such disk in `lsblk`. I do have one that does not seem to appear in `ras-mc-ctl` given this formula however and it has MAJOR = 8 and MINOR = 0. Any ideas?